# Admob's banner in android app is bigger than screen

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm having some problems trying to integrate an admob banner in my app.

I create an adView via xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/adMobIDSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And in my main activity I invoke admob like this

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)       // Emulator
            .addTestDevice("001917fb63241f")
            .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But when I run my application in my SG SII I get this error message:

---

### 02-24 19:25:28.798: W/Ads(26575): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 480x75 pixels, but only has 432x690 pixels.

Its like Admob is ignoring the size of the banner I'm requesting. I've tried everything and I'm running out of ideas :(

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have posted the entire layout XML. I suspect you have padding or set a margin for one of the elements enclosing @id/bannerLayout. Remove the padding/margin (nb it might be in a style you have applied).

I also suggest you alter the layout_width and layout_eights as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/adMobIDSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use:

```
 ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
```

instead of:

```
 ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

then the banner should adjust to the screen size.

BTW: it is weird that your available screen size is so small (432x690) => You should review the layout file where your banner-layout snippet is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer,

I finally get the solution, Eclipse by default puts the following information on the main layout:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Removing this lines makes the trick :D

Comment: I told you to review your main layout file ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It might because that your root layout has padding/margins.
On a 800X480 screen, you should make sure the banner is occupying the whole width of the display area.